# How to see all tags in TortoiseHg. Any handy way of switching and computing diffs between them?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs, tortoisehg

Is there a way to see all tags in Tortoise Mercurial?  For example, is there a way to filter the visualization of all my commits and show only those that have tags in them?

Besides viewing only commits with tags, does TortoiseHg support any way of quickly switching or visualizing diffs between them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- Did you try to explore THG interface (namely - workbench toolbar buttons)? Fourth from left button do any filters ("tagged()" is predefined)

[image: Tags filter]

- To view the differences between two tags, right click on the two selected tags

[image: Context menu]